# Solving Linear equations with constraint in Python

Tags: python, linear-equation

I have a system of linear equations with some constraints. I would appreciate it if someone could help me solving this system of equations in Python.

[image: System of linear equations with some constraints]

Comment: Please ask a question related to a problem with an actual code. Have you tried something yet?

Comment: As it stands you are asking for programming help for free.  Do some homework, come up with something half working, or ask a specific question.

Comment: You can use a python library such as [PuLP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP).

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly easy to solve with sympy: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve

Add all your equations to a list. Then pass that list to `linsolve()`. You'll probably loop through each value of `j` to generate those equations.