# Solving Linear Systems of Equations With Constraints

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra

I am working on a project which requires the solution to a very large system of equations (around 3,000 variables). I am currently using numpy.linalg.lstsq to solve it, which is working fine. However, I need it to find a solution where all the variables are positive, and lstsq does not seem to offer any ability to place constraints on the solution. Does anyone know how to do this in python?

Thanks in advance.

Note: A somewhat similar question was asked previously ([Solving Linear equations with constraint in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583034/solving-linear-equations-with-constraint-in-python)), but its answer does not work for me.

Comment: It sounds like you have a quadratic programming problem (minimize sum of squared errors subject to constraints) which is a subtopic in constrained optimization. Search for resources with those keywords should find something. I am aware of L-BFGS-B for which there might be a Python interface, no doubt there are many other packages. You should consider working in some other language than Python and then figuring out how to port the solution. Another package to search for is qpOASES. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Not least squares; you need to apply the simplex method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PulP.

```
python -m pip install pulp
```

With Pulp, you don’t have to mathematically modify your problem ( positive to negative) or use vectors and matrices.